# Does hibernate reuse object stored in memory or does it create new object every time?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Having simple class:

```
@Entity
class Person{
    @Id
    private String name;

    @ManyTo@Many
    @JoinTable(..)
    List<Person> friends;
}
```

Retrieving `Person` from database also retrieve his friends (based on fetching strategy but lets omit this).

If I retrieve person with name "Alice", and she has "Bob" in friends, Both entities Alice and BoB.

So:

```
void printFriends() {
    Person p = personDao.getPersonByName("Alice");
    for(Person f: p.getFriends())
        System.out.println(f.getName())
}
```

Here the data is retrieved from DB, object is created, friends are loaded , and after function stops executing garbage collector does his work.

However, what if I want to save `Person p`?

```
static List<Person> loggedPersons;

    void printFriends() {
        Person p = personDao.getPersonByName("Alice");
        loggedPersons.add(p);
        for(Person f: p.getFriends())
          System.out.println(f.getName()) // "Bob"
    }
```

Here the garbage collector cannot do his stuff. The object `p` is still referenced in the list, so now when I do:

```
Person p_1 = personDao.getPersonByName("Bob");
```

Will the hibernate reuse the object from Alices friend? Or does it create new object in memory?

If it creates new object, is there a way how to make workaround for this, so the List of friends will get cleared?

In app where serve saves logged users as in example and also returns his friends would cause it huge memory usage, or is there some pattern/functionality I am missing?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Regardless of the question, if you want to save memory (I guess you're asking because you can have some performance problems), then if you just want to retireve only `Person.name` and only `Friend.name` in order to display them in the aplication, then use projections and [DTOs](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/entities-dtos-use-projection/) instead of fetching whole entities. This can greatly speed up some operations.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/

Answer (score 2):

A good read is [this](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache).

By default Hibernate uses 2 levels of caching, I quote:

> As most other fully-equipped ORM frameworks, Hibernate has the concept of first-level cache. It is a session scoped cache which ensures that each entity instance is loaded only once in the persistent context.
>
> Once the session is closed, first-level cache is terminated as well. This is actually desirable, as it allows for concurrent sessions to work with entity instances in isolation from each other.
>
> On the other hand, second-level cache is SessionFactory-scoped, meaning it is shared by all sessions created with the same session factory. When an entity instance is looked up by its id (either by application logic or by Hibernate internally, e.g. when it loads associations to that entity from other entities), and if second-level caching is enabled for that entity, the following happens:

You can turn the second level cache off if you so desire, but of course this will lead to a performance penalty.
You can also limit the lifetime of cached entities, reducing memory use that way for possibly no performance penalty, as well as tune the cache strategy for individual classes and queries.